# How to make MainPageSuffix work in Google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, web-hosting, content-type, hugo

I have a simple hugo site, deployed in google cloud storage as static web site and its working fine with one issue, Whenever the subfolder is requested in browser with / , the browser trying to download and failing. without / its working fine.

ie, http://mysite/ is working fine, but http://mysite/subfolder/ is not working but trying to download it and fails. whenever http://mysite or http://mysite/subfolder is called the browser working fine.

Please see supporting images and help to solve the issue.. Thanks.

What Google document says..
[image: Google Doc]

While testing its ok,
[image: Working ok in hugo server]

But after deployed to Google Cloud storage, its behaving like this..
[image: but not in google cloud storage]

Please check the faulty url
[Here](http://tn.organicfarmer.in/surya/)

Please check the working url 
[Here](http://tn.organicfarmer.in/surya)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved...

x-goog-metageneration:1 works, x-goog-metageneration:2 fails.

So as per https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers
I deleted and recreated the surya folder, now its working.

But why x-goog-metageneration:2 fails, x-goog-metageneration:1 working... 
Google only knows.